# In Matlab, how can I remove nodes with no edges in a directed graph?

Tags: matlab, plot, graph, directed-graph

I enter this:

```
plot(digraph([1 2 3 10],[2 3 1 1]))
```

And the figure shows [image]

How can I remove the nodes 8,9,4,5,6 and 7? Is there a setting to not show any nodes that dont have edges?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can manually relabel the edges using [`unique`](https://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/unique.html), so that there are no holes in the list of node numbers. To maintain the original node names, pass them as fourth input to [`digraph`](https://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/digraph.html) in the form of a cell array of strings:

```
S = [1 2 3 10];
T = [2 3 1 1];
[u, ~, w] = unique([S T]);
plot(digraph(w(1:end/2), w(end/2+1:end), [], cellstr(num2str(u.'))))
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Another way, by using matlab functions created exactly for graphs / networks, i.e. [indegree](https://ch.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/digraph.indegree.html), [outdegree](https://ch.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/digraph.outdegree.html), and [rmnode](https://ch.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/graph.rmnode.html).
Notes:

- to always keep the same labels / names for the nodes, please assign the labels / names to the function [digraph](https://ch.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/digraph.html).
- use the [indegree](https://ch.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/digraph.indegree.html) and [outdegree](https://ch.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/digraph.outdegree.html) functions to find the isolated nodes, i.e. with both [indegree](https://ch.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/digraph.indegree.html) and [outdegree](https://ch.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/digraph.outdegree.html) equal to zero. Just for a sake of completeness: if you had an undirected graph / network, you could simply use the [degree](https://ch.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/graph.degree.html) function to spot the isolated nodes (use this: `find(degree(N) == 0)`).
- use the [rmnode](https://ch.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/graph.rmnode.html) function to remove the isolated nodes from your graph / network.

Here you are the relative code:

```
names_of_nodes = string(1:10);
N = digraph([1 2 3 10],[2 3 1 1],[], names_of_nodes);
isolated_nodes = find(indegree(N) + outdegree(N) == 0);
N = rmnode(N,isolated_nodes);
plot(N)
```

[image]